# Hosting a java servlet on Amazon AWS

Tags: java, servlets, amazon-ec2

I have a java servlet (.war file) that needs to be hosted on Amazon AWS.

Does anyone know of the steps involved, in form of a tutorial that will help me do this?

Answer (score 8):

From the sounds of it you are not familiar with the ins and outs of deploying a web server or Java servlet container such as Tomcat. That said, I reckon the quickest and easiest way for you to deploy a war file to AWS is to use Amazon's [Elastic Beanstalk](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/) functionality (check out the section titled 'For Java Developers'). If you have managed to create a war file then Elastic Beanstalk should get you up and running pretty quickly.

If you're keen to get to know more about the nuts and bolts of deploying a war file then you should have a read about how to setup and deploy [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/deployer-howto.html). FYI Tomcat is a web server and Java servlet container. It can be installed on AWS.

Comment: +1 for suggesting Elastic Beanstalk, it's definitely the way to go if one just want to deploy war files.

Comment: I have played around with tomcat. Sometimes you just need a plug and play to deploy a war instead of messing with it. A war is more or less a self contained object that need not require messing with container setup.